# Open attachment for user in the UI in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ravendb, attachment

What I am trying to do - When user clicks on a link, get the attachment from RavenDB and open it automatically for the user.

On Click of a link - I pass the attachment id of a attachment (already saved in RavenDB) to the controller method via view/ajax. Once inside the controller method, I want to get the attachment and display/open the attachment for the user.

View :

```
<a href onclick="GetAttachment('<%= Model.Id %>');"> See attachment </a>
```

Ajax/JS

```
function GetAttachment(id) {   

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/ControllerName/GetMethod',
    data: id,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (msg) {
        if (msg.Success) {               
        }
        else {               
        }
     }       
  });
}
```

Controller :

```
    public string GetMethod(string id)
    {          
        var dbCommands = session.Advanced.DatabaseCommands;
        var attachment = dbCommands.GetAttachment(id);
       //Here - How do I use above lines of code to get hold of the 
       // attachment and open it for the user.
    }
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: What is the type of attachment? Is it Stream or something else? In all cases you need to return FileResult from your Action.

Comment: when saved its converted into stream.. and saved as byte information..it can be any type of file.. .pdf or .doc etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:
Controller:

```
public FileResult GetMethod(string id)
{          
    var name = "filename.extension";
    var dbCommands = session.Advanced.DatabaseCommands;
    var attachment = dbCommands.GetAttachment(id);
    var stream = new MemoryStream(attachment.Data);
    return new FileStreamResult(stream, name);
}
```

View:

> @Html.ActionLink("See attachment", "GetMethod", "ControllerName", new {id = ModelId}, null)

You need get MemoryStream of file from database or transfer your file into MemoryStream

Comment: MemoryStream attachment = dbCommands.GetAttachment(id); will not work as "dbCommands.GetAttachment(id)" is not memorystream type.. it is raven.abstractions.data.attachment type..

Comment: I don't know what you get from db. But you need to transfer it to MemoryStream to pass it to FileStreamResult

Comment: But this does not open the file for user in UI? does it? am i missing anything?

Comment: User click on reference and browser will download file to user. Browser can't display file of any type, so user can open downloaded file with other program

Comment: what do you mean by "click on reference"

Comment: @Html.ActionLink("See attachment", "GetMethod", "ControllerName", new {id = ModelId}, null) generate reference link on GetMethod

Comment: works great.. thank you for your help. How can I have this open in a separate window..

Comment: If you want it to open in a new window, just create the link for the user with target="_blank", or use some javascript to open it in a new window if you want to be strict xhtml.  No need for ajax if you're opening it in a new window, though.

Answer (score 3):

The RavenDB `Attachment` class has a `Data` property of type `Func<Stream>` which is a [thunk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk_%28functional_programming%29) to the byte stream for the attachment. The stream is what you need to return in your MVC controller:

```
public FileResult GetMethod(string id)
{          
    var dbCommands = session.Advanced.DatabaseCommands;
    var attachment = dbCommands.GetAttachment(id);
    return File(attachment.Data(), "fileName");
}
```